# jQuery append HTML with javascript link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a situation where I should append html with jQuery. Within this html there is an a-tag with javascript as link.

How can I solve this?

```
$(".messages-wrapper").append('<li class="chat-wrapper"><a class="chat" href="javascript:openChat('http://domain.com/Messenger.aspx'">Chat öffnen<span></span><small>Chat öffnen</small></a></li>')
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can escape single or double quotes in a string with a backslash.

```
'... href="javascript:openChat(\'http...\')">...'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably having problems because of the quotes in the string.  The single quotes are terminating the string early and causing a javascript error.

Consider, however, applying the hander at the same time that you append the html.

```
 var link = $('<li class="chat-wrapper"><a class="chat" href="http://domain.com/Messenger.aspx">Chat öffnen<span></span><small>Chat öffnen</small></a></li>')
            .find('a')
            .click( function() {
                 openChat($(this).attr('href'));
                 return false;
            });
 link.appendTo(".messages-wrapper");
```

Comment: +1, will degrade gracefully if javascript is not enabled, though I'm guessing the chat page needs JS anyway.

Comment: @Joel: A bit moot to consider how code created with Javascript would behave if Javascript was not enabled...

Comment: You are missing the point completely. If Javascript isn't enabled, the code that creates the link doesn't execute.

Comment: @Guffa, you are correct. However, I still discourage embedding javascript in markup, even javascript generated markup.

Comment: @Guffa - you're right, of course, you caught me before my morning coffee and I responded without re-reading my answer.  In my case what I usually do is simply put the HTML inline and add handlers later so I assumed that's how I had answered.  If the chat page does require javascript, though, this would be a *better* way to add the HTML as it then wouldn't exist unless javascript were enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to escape the apostrophes in the string using `\'`:

```
$(".messages-wrapper")
.append('<li class="chat-wrapper"><a class="chat" href="javascript:openChat(\'http://domain.com/Messenger.aspx\'">Chat öffnen<span></span><small>Chat öffnen</small></a></li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a nested append off of a created opject, to do the click action.

```
$('.messages-wrapper')
  .append(
    $('<li class="chat-wrapper" />")
      .append(
        $('<a class="chat" href="http://domain.com/Messenger.aspx"><small>Chat öffnen</small></a>')
          .click(function(){
            openChat(this.href);
            return false;
          })
      )
  );
```

This is easier to read the intention anyway, imho.